# Using CSV file variables in postman runner

Tags: csv, postman

I am using postman to test an API. With pre-defined variable or even environment variables everything is working well. However I want to run my test with data from a CSV file in the 'Runner'. So I started the runner and choose the right CSV file and environment. However the tests are now failing, as the variables cannot be found.

So for example I have:

`{"amount": "{{amount}}"}`

And amount is a field in my CSV file as well (in the first row, and CSV file is with unix file endings).

As this was not working, I tried adding this in the Pre-Request Script too:

`postman.setGlobalVariable("amount", data.amount);`

But this isn't working as well - amount is still undefined.

So I do not know what to do, as I don't know how to map get the amount of my CSV file in the test Body. Do I have to put it in the Header or like I have done in the Pre-request Script? As all the instructions I found from blogs about postman runner are not working anymore, I seriously do not know how this could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure your first row in CSV has "amount" as the header variable. Header is case sensitive to your variable i.e. "amount" is not same as "Amount"
   e.g.

   amount
   100
   150
   300
   400
   550
   700
2. In Runner window, select the Data File Type as CSV and check if you could see the preview as this:
   [amount CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyFNm.png)

Comment: Hi, No way to do so in manual execution by passing the csv file in a form-data body with a File as argument ?
Not sure how to access the data in the csv from the Tests script without the collection runner iteration mechanism

Answer (score -2):

This works to test the response code against a code saved in a json file - I think you can change it a bit to validate any variable

under Test add

```
var code = responseCode.code.toString();
tests["expected code"] = code === data.code; //assuming the json file has "code" : "200"
```